# Force UICollectionView to stop scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

A user performs a quick swipe gesture to make a UICollectionView start scrolling (it will gradually come to an halt).

How can I programmatically force the scrolling to come to an immediate stop?
To clarify, I want to allow the deceleration but I need to be able to stop it in code.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
[self.collectionView setContentOffset:self.collectionView.contentOffset animated:NO];
```

the `contentOffset` property is constantly updated as the collectionView scrolls (even via animation) so at the time of calling the above, it should hopefully force the collectionView to stop its existing animation.

Comment: Does not work, either the y or the x value needs to be changed.

I used this and it works:

    `CGPoint offset = self.collectionView.contentOffset;
    (self.collectionView.contentOffset.y > 0) ? offset.y-- : offset.y++;
    [self.collectionView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];`

Answer (score 36):

Try this one. Worked for me. :)

```
self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: They can still tap items to scroll to them :/

Answer (score 14):

For Swift 3:

```
collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 6):

if you have the `pagingEnabled` and `scrollEnabled` properties set to `true` than this should work:

```
self.collectionView.scrollEnabled = false
self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Adopt the following `scrollViewDelegate` method to pick up when the user lets go of dragging the collectionView.

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset;
```

You can then just create your own animation block to set whichever speed/final destination you think looks best using the `contentOffset` property.

Comment: This will not fit my scenario. I need to be able to interrupt the animation at any time.

Comment: Haha okay then just set the contentOffset property at anytime. It will force it to stop.

Comment: `self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;` sets the content offset to the beginning, but it does not abort the animation. It just continues off from 0,0.

Comment: You have to do setContentOffSet:yourOffset animated:NO